# Lua function return

Tags: lua

I was wondering if there is any significant difference between

```
function foo()
  do something
  return bar()
end
```

and

```
function foo()
  do something
  bar()
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two main differences.

The first returns the values returned from `bar` to the caller of `foo`. The second ignores them entirely.

The first also gets treated as a tail-call and as such can get eliminated to save a stack frame (prevents recursion from blowing up your stack) whereas the second does not.

Comment: Lets say that I dont really need the return value of bar. Would it be better to use the second one?

Comment: definitely not. You can read  here http://www.lua.org/pil/6.3.html to know why the return somefun() form is always bettere if the last line of your function was somefun()

Comment: The only reason to avoid the tail-call usage would be to get better error messages (as tail-calls make the stack trace harder to read). But that's not likely to be a general concern and much more likely to be a "can't figure out what is going on so let's help me debug" temporary avoidance.

Comment: @Mico If it makes sense to return the result of `bar` from `foo`, then do so. Otherwise don't.